# WooCommerce - doesn't show product when using woocommerce.php

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Strange situation - I installed WooCommerce, and by default the /shop, /cart, etc. pages work fine.  However, the formatting is off, so I tried making a "woocommerce.php" template as directed.  This contains the call to "woocommerce_content()"

Now when I load the /shop page for instance, everything shows EXCEPT the products - they aren't there.  Without the woocommerce.php template, the products show just fine.

Is there something I'm missing? 
-jim

Comment: Welcome to [WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). Third party plugins are off-topic, see [help/on-topic]. Try the support forums at [WooThemes](http://support.woothemes.com), or [WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woocommerce).

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer - might be obscure, but still might help someone:

Apparently the custom navigation template messed up / overwrote the "$posts" array, so I just saved the original, and restored it after including the navigation:

```
<?php
$saved_posts = $posts;
get_template_part('tpl-nav');
$posts = $saved_posts;
?>
```

Just added to to the top of the woocommerce.php template and it fixed the problem.